# Clarification of notation for a vector space $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, homological-algebra

I am reading an article on homology and manifolds, and came across this notation for a vector space: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Specifically, the text of the article says:

> For simplicity, our treatment of persistence modules adapted from [7]
>   is restricted to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-vector spaces (in general,
>   persistence can be defined for vector spaces over any field,
>   $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is used here for computational simplicity).

Does this represent the set of vector spaces with only odd integers? That does not make much sense. I was not clear on the intent here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is just the field with $2$ elements which is more commonly denoted by $\mathbb{F}_2$.

So the article doesn't look at "the vector space $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$" but rather on vector spaces over the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh okay. Haha, Yeah, that notation was throwing me off. I appreciate it. That makes much more sense.